How to remove an aerator metal cap which is broken and plastic part is stuck in the faucet
When trying to unscrew the aerator using a plumber wrench I broke the outer metal cap but the inner portion of the metal cap as well as plastic portion of the aerator got stuck with faucet. Now I want to remove it completely so that I can fix a new aerator.

Pictures will help since there are many designs.

We could use some pictures to help us see what you see. Please take some good, in-focus pictures of the faucet, especially underneath where the issue is. You can [edit] your Question here to insert them, using the "mountain and sun" button, or if you just link to them someone can help embed them in the question. Also be sure to take the [tour] to get familiar with DIY.SE!

use a flame to soften/melt the plastic.

Pipe wrenches have no business on a faucet. They're either finger-tight or have small flats for a less destructive wrench.
With the little detail you've provided the only answer I can give is to get whatever tool you have on hand to grab and twist. A needle-nose plier might fit in the openings.
